# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Eclipse, Maven project

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
On creating a maven project from Eclipse And try to creating object of a class in src/test/java

The issue is not there when try to execute on non maven project. And trying to create a object of the class in 
same package.

I can see a lots of people are saying to clean the project, Setting up env variable but noting works for me.

Pleas help. I am completely stuck up these.! here is the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The class HeWillDo.java is in test package. When you build your project, it will not be part of loaded classes.

Your current attempt suggests that you want to use a class written for testing or assist in testing into live code, which is not correct.

Comment: But i can see the same project exported into another machine runs successfully.

Comment: Please learn about the project structure and package hierarchy of Java project and its dependency. This will clear your basic doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your Package hierarchy.
We can't and should not access anything from **"src/main/java"** resource java to **"src/test/java"** . These are two different sets of package hierarchy. Test class wont be available in Main class but you can access public class of main into Test.

You can test the same but after moving "HeWillDo.java" to "src/main/java" any package or same package.

Comment: But i can see the same project exported into another machine runs successfully.